# pkg-config --exists fuse fails

Tags: fuse, pkg-config

I am trying to install fuse-python package, when I run

```
python setup.py build
```

It fails, when I checked the contents of setup.py I found this line

```
if os.system('pkg-config --exists fuse 2> /dev/null') == 0
```

this line fails. Also when I check PKG_CONFIG_PATH

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

it prints nothing. Any sort of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

In Ubuntu the package is `libfuse-dev`, so to install `sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you haven't got the fuse development package installed. You don't say which OS you are using, but on openSuSE

```
zypper install fuse-devel
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I used `sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. If you have a 64 bit ubuntu like me just install pkg-config via
  `sudo apt install pkg-config`
The problem was, that the 32 bit Version of pkg-config was installed. By installing pkg-config again it installs the 64bit version